# How to Remove Registry Audit Rules?

Tags: powershell, registry, acl

I am trying to remove registry auditing rules I've previously set, but it's not working and I have no idea what I'm missing/doing wrong.

Setting auditing rules on a registry key works fine:

```
$RegistryKey = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop'
$AuditIdentityReference = "Everyone"
$AuditRegistryRights = "SetValue,Delete"
$AuditInheritanceFlags = "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"
$AuditPropagationFlags = "None"
$AuditFlags = "success"
$AuditRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAuditRule ($AuditIdentityReference,$AuditRegistryRights,$AuditInheritanceFlags,$AuditPropagationFlags,$AuditFlags)
$ACL = Get-Acl $RegistryKey
$ACL.AddAuditRule($AuditRule)
$ACL | Set-Acl -Path $RegistryKey
Get-Acl $RegistryKey -Audit | Select Path -ExpandProperty Audit | fl *
```

My understanding is I need to build the `$Rule` I wish to remove and then use `.RemoveAuditRule($Rule)`. But although the method returns 'true', the audit rule is still in place:

```
$RegistryKey = 'HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop'
$AuditIdentityReference = "Everyone"
$AuditRegistryRights = "SetValue,Delete"
$AuditInheritanceFlags = "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"
$AuditPropagationFlags = "None"
$AuditFlags = "success"
$AuditRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAuditRule ($AuditIdentityReference,$AuditRegistryRights,$AuditInheritanceFlags,$AuditPropagationFlags,$AuditFlags)
$ACL = Get-Acl $RegistryKey
$ACL.RemoveAuditRule($AuditRule)
$ACL | Set-Acl -Path $RegistryKey
Get-Acl $RegistryKey -Audit | Select Path -ExpandProperty Audit | fl *
```

Doing something similar on the file system though works fine:

```
$Dir = 'C:\Testing'
$ACL = get-acl $Dir
$Rule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule("Everyone","CreateDirectories,CreateFiles,Delete,DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles,Write,WriteData","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Success,Failure")
$ACL.AddAuditRule($Rule)
$ACL | Set-Acl -Path $Dir
$ACL.RemoveAuditRule($Rule)
$ACL | Set-Acl -Path $Dir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When fetching the ACL you didn't include SACLs, so there was nothing to remove.

Change this:

```psh
$ACL = Get-Acl $RegistryKey
$ACL.RemoveAuditRule($AuditRule)
$ACL | Set-Acl -Path $RegistryKey
```

into this:

```psh
$ACL = Get-Acl $RegistryKey -Audit
$ACL.RemoveAuditRule($AuditRule)
$ACL | Set-Acl -Path $RegistryKey
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Bingo - thanks for the second pair of eyes and correction!
Although, I'm not confident I understand how my file/folder example is working without explicitly getting the audit data for the security descriptor from the system access control list.